# TypeError: Cannot read property 'renderView' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a main page with 2 buttons in `React.js`: `Option 1` and  `Option 2`. If a user clicks on `Option 1`, this user should be redirected to `Main1` page. If he/she clicks on `Option 2`, then this user is redirected to `Main2`. Sounds quite simple, but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'renderView' of null
App.render
C:/test/src/App.js:15
  12 | 
  13 | render() {
  14 |   
> 15 |   switch (this.state.renderView) {
     | ^  16 |     case 1:
  17 |       return (
  18 |         <div className="App">
```

This is my code of `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Header } from './components/Header';
import { Header1 } from './components/xai/Header1';
import { Header2 } from './components/fairness/Header2';
import { Main } from './components/Main';
import { Main1 } from './components/xai/Main1';
import { Main2 } from './components/fairness/Main2';

class App extends Component {

  clickBtn = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.setState({
      renderView: +e.target.parentNode.value
    });
  };

  render() {

    switch (this.state.renderView) {
      case 1:
        return (
          <div className="App">
              <div className="App-header">
                <Header1 />
              </div>
              <div className="App-main">
                <Main1 />
              </div>
          </div>
        );
      case 2:
        return (
          <div className="App">
              <div className="App-header">
                <Header2 />
              </div>
              <div className="App-main">
                <Main2 />
              </div>
          </div>
        );
      default:
        return (
          <div className="App">
              <div className="App-header">
                <Header />
              </div>
              <div className="App-main">
                <Main clickBtn={this.clickBtn} />
              </div>
          </div>
        );
    }
  }

}

export default App;
```

This is the code of `Main.js` where I have two buttons:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    card: {
        minWidth: 350
      },
    button: {
        fontSize: "12px",
        margin: "theme.spacing.unit",
        minWidth: 350
    },
    extendedIcon: {
        marginRight: "theme.spacing.unit"
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: '20px',
        minWidth: 350,
        margin: "theme.spacing.unit"
    }
});


export function Main() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Grid
          container
          spacing={0}
          direction="column"
          alignItems="center"
          justify="center"
          style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}
        >
          <Card className={classes.card}>
            <Typography align="center" className={classes.title}>
              Select the option
            </Typography>
            <CardContent>
              <Grid item xs={3}>
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  size="medium"
                  color="primary"
                  className={classes.button}
                  value="1"
                  onClick={this.props.clickBtn}
                >
                  Option 1
                </Button>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={3}>
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  size="medium"
                  color="primary"
                  className={classes.button}
                  value="2"
                  onClick={this.props.clickBtn}
                >
                  Option 2
                </Button>
              </Grid>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

How to fix this issue?

If other classes should be provided here, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't create `state` for the `App` component:

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {renderView: null}
    render(){
      ...
```

And note that `this.clickBtn` is undefined too, so you gotta define it.

since Main.js is a `functional` component it doesn't include the `this` keyword.

```
export function Main(props){
....
     onClick={props.clickBtn}
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it. But still it does not work. The error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined` next to `onClick={this.props.clickBtn}` in `Main.js`.